# Space between <p> elements (not margin? example shown)

Tags: html, css

Hey I am writing this basic forum software and in each post the `<p>` elements have these huge gaps between them, I can reduce their size by reducing the Line Height.
http://www.uk-sf.com/forums.php?view=topic:102
if you go to this link you can see one of the topics in which all the posts have these spaced out `<p>` elements.

Squadron Leader Butler's post in particular has a lot of writing and so you can see the excessive gap between the `P` elements.

If you could please help with what is causing that gap and how I could get rid of it.

Comment: Please read [Something on my web site doesn't work. Can I just paste a link to it?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/125997/something-on-my-web-site-doesnt-work-can-i-just-paste-a-link-to-it). Questions that depend on external resources to be understood become useless when the external resource goes away or is fixed. Create an [SSCCE](http://www.sscce.org/) instead.

Comment: Why are the `<p>`'s nested in a `<pre>`??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is that you are using a `<pre>` block around the post. (The [pre](http://developers.whatwg.org/grouping-content.html#the-pre-element) element does not collapse HTML whitespace by default.)

You **should** remove the pre.

Alternatively, you can set [whitespace](http://www.htmldog.com/reference/cssproperties/white-space/) to normal in `.postbody pre`, like this: `.postbody pre { white-space: normal. }`.

Comment: Thanks, is there anything I can add into the stylesheet to fix the spacing? Is the only solution to remove the pre?

Comment: Why would you want to use the <pre>`s in the first place? Remove them rather than trying to "fix" it.

Comment: Edited an answer to @user3211248 .

Answer (score 2):

Text in a pre element is displayed in a fixed-width font, and it preserves both spaces and line breaks.

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/4dgaurav/aKPW7/)

```
<pre>
this is example
this     is     example
this is example
</pre>
```

[http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_pre.asp](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag%5fpre.asp)

Comment: Good answer. But please don't link to w3schools: http://www.w3fools.com/

Comment: @ANeves: thank you so much! I never knew about that.